# How do I launch anaconda GUI inside WSL?

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xcb, mobaxterm

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/install-anaconda-wsl-windows-10-ubuntu-linux-app.html) which details how to install conda on WSL.

I have installed conda without issue but I can't launch the GUI on the last step. The guide indicated that once the conda is installed within WSL, I should be able to launch the conda GUI through MobaXterm as shown below:
[image]

The issue is that I get the following error:

**(MobaXterm WSL-Ubuntu) Terminal output:**

```
(base) me@DESKTOP:~$ anaconda-navigator
2022-12-16 01:02:41,329 - WARNING linux_scaling.get_scaling_factor_using_dbus:32
An exception occurred during fetching list of system display settings.

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, webgl, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
(base) me@DESKTOP:~$
```

I've tried reinstalling xcb but this had no effect, I've also looked online and not found anything relevant. Does anyone know how to resolve this so I can launch anaconda GUI through WSL?

[image: Terminal output]